# Why is in the reaction of cyclic unsaturated aldehydes with hydrazine and hydrogen peroxide the aldehyde preserved?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, carbonyl-compounds

> **Question**
>   What is the product of this reaction?
>   [image]
>
> The answer given:
>   [image]

At first, I thought this was a typical Wolff-Kishner reduction, but then I saw the reagents didn't match up (no $\ce{OH-}$).

How is this getting formed? Shouldn't the $\ce{CHO}$ group be reduced? What am I missing here?

Comment: This reaction worries me: mostly because hydrazine is known to be explosive (via oxidation to $\ce{N2(g)}$) in the presence of strong oxidants and hydrogen peroxide is not the most stable molecule either: $$\ce{H2N2 + H2O2 -> N2 + 2H2O}$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductions_with_diimide However, peroxide and hydrazine is not listed as a common method of preparing diimide *in situ*.

Comment: Sanofi have demonstrated this reduction method at large scale on artemisinic acid and it's not without its calorimetric challenges.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reaction of $\ce{H2O2}$ with hydrazine forms diazene, $\ce{HN=NH}$.  This reacts in a syn fashion to deliver both hydrogens to the same side of the alkene.

Comment: Thanks, I can relate this question to our course now - diimide indeed selectively reduces C-C double bonds in preference to polar bonds.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's a di-imide which itself gets oxidised to give up nascent hydrogen and reduce the other reactant.
Thus, when you react it with an alkene , hydrogen add on the same side i.e. syn addition. Unlike $\ce{N2H4/KOH}$, it is not strong enough to reduce carbonyl groups. Therefore you get a different product.